# Create multi-row summaries with dplyr, for example grouped table()

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

My data set consists of observations of plants of multiple varieties (genotypes) which I have for multiple 
environments. This example data contains one line for each observation 
I have. It lists the plant genotype and in which environment the observation
was made.

```
nObs <- 500
data <- tibble(Gt  = sample(sprintf("%02d",1:20),nObs,T),
               Env = sample(LETTERS\[1:8\],nObs,T)
               # The measured plant trait would also go here but is irrelevant for now.
               )
```

What I want is a table which shows me for each genotype in how many environments
it is repeated how many times. For example, If my genotype `01` has two replications
in five environments but only one in another two environments, the output
I expect is:

```
Genotype  nRepl  nEnv
---------------------
 A        2      5
 A        1      2
```

I have found a possibility using `do`, but it is slow because `do` expects
a data frame to be created for each data subgroup which contains the summary information. This creates a lot of 
overhead, as you can see when profiling:

```
profvis::profvis(for(1:10) idea1())  #idea1 is defined below
```

[image: profiler output]

Is there another approach, perhaps without using `do(.)`, which gives this result?

My ideas up to now are shown below:

---

This returns the number of observations I have for each genotype in each
environment (=replications):

```
data %>% count(Gt, Env) 

## # A tibble: 158 x 3
##    Gt    Env       n
##    <chr> <chr> <int>
##  1 01    A         2
##  2 01    B         1
##  3 01    C         2
##  4 01    D         2
##  5 01    E         6
##  6 01    F         4
##  7 01    G         5
##  8 01    H         3
##  9 02    A         1
## 10 02    B         2
## # ... with 148 more rows
```

These are the three approaches I could come up with so far. All use `do`:

```
idea1 <- function(){
  data %>% count(Gt, Env) %>% group_by(Gt) %>%
    do({
      t <- table(.$n)
      tibble(nRpl = names(t), nEnv = as.integer(t))
    })
}

idea2 <- function(){
  data %>% count(Gt, Env) %>% group_by(Gt) %>%
    do({
      t <- table(.$n)
      data.frame(nRpl = names(t), nEnv = as.integer(t), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    })
}

idea3 <- function(){
  data %>% count(Gt, Env) %>% group_by(Gt) %>%
    do({
      t <- table(.$n)
      data.frame(nRpl = names(t), nEnv = as.integer(t), stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                 check.names = FALSE, check.rows = FALSE)
    })
}
```

This is the output  I want:

```
idea1()

## # A tibble: 93 x 3
## # Groups:   Gt [20]
##    Gt    nRpl   nEnv
##    <chr> <chr> <int>
##  1 01    1         1
##  2 01    2         3
##  3 01    3         1
##  4 01    4         1
##  5 01    5         1
##  6 01    6         1
##  7 02    1         1
##  8 02    2         4
##  9 02    4         1
## 10 02    6         1
## # ... with 83 more rows
```

Speed comparison:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark({idea1()},{idea3()},{idea4()}, times = 20)

## Unit: milliseconds
##             expr       min        lq     mean   median       uq      max
##  {     idea1() } 299.21640 373.87930 435.2567 427.8721 460.7488 693.9279
##  {     idea3() }  80.03300 100.25709 144.8413 124.8140 182.9211 300.3150
##  {     idea4() }  83.04371  98.18572 122.6464 108.1945 141.0208 216.3999
##  neval
##     20
##     20
##     20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `count` twice, the second time counting the number of replications calculated the first time:

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(47)    # for sampling reproducibility

data <- tibble(Gt  = sample(sprintf("%02d", 1:20), 500, replace = TRUE),
               Env = sample(LETTERS[1:8], 500, replace = TRUE))

data %>% 
    count(Gt, Env) %>% 
    count(Gt, n) %>% 
    rename(nRpl = n, nEnv = nn)    # make better names
#> # A tibble: 85 x 3
#>    Gt     nRpl  nEnv
#>    <chr> <int> <int>
#>  1 01        2     1
#>  2 01        3     4
#>  3 01        4     3
#>  4 02        2     1
#>  5 02        3     1
#>  6 02        4     3
#>  7 02        6     1
#>  8 03        1     3
#>  9 03        2     1
#> 10 03        3     1
#> # ... with 75 more rows
```